# SWF is not a loadable module when compiling from flash builder 4.6 but not 4.0

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

Having a very strange issue on an inherited project. The developer who built the project (using fb 4.0 and flex 3.0.0.477) is able to compile it and the application works just fine, both locally and on the server. However, if I take the identical code and compile it using fb 4.6 and the same flex sdk, the application works locally, but starts failing to load modules on the server, giving a "SWF is not a loadable module" error. There are no other errors from the debug sessions.

All crossdomain policy files appear to be in place. The module even begins loading, but receives the error after 5 - 10% downloaded.

I also tried setting the application domain using modLoader.applicationDomain = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;, with no results.

Thanks!

Comment: Is everything being hosted/served through the same domain? Also the IDE version itself really shouldn't make any difference, the only things it has are configuration for the flash player version and build paths etc., under the hood regardless of ide it's using bin\mxmlc to do the compilation.  I would verify in the build path settings that the framework is set for merging into code instead of RSLs but can't really think of anything else: http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/2007/03/swf_is_not_a_loadable_module.html

Comment: The modules are in the same domain as the application. Some modules load resources from other domains, but all modules are failing to load. Also, build settings for framwork linkage are on SDK default (merged into code)

Comment: Incidentally, I tried building the original developer's working code base in flex builder 3/windows, and got the same behavior. Since both flex builder 3 and flash builder 4.6 are showing the same results, it seems to indicate an issue related to his builder settings. Or am I missing something?

Comment: No that sounds like it could be correct if you're having to let eclipse modify the project settings when importing to a different version of Flash Builder it might be messing something up when doing that transition.  Specifically with regard to the modules are you also rebuilding those, the modules can be built "optimized" meaning the don't include bytecode for classes the application will have (making the modules overall smaller, and a particular application has to be selected for the optimization).

Comment: It's not optimized on his machine or mine.

Comment: In the compiler settings within the project properties I believe you can use the -link-report "C:\somefile.txt" to get the configuration that's being used for the build, maybe try using that on both and see if the output is different.  Actually not sure that's the flag I'm thinking of, looking through the list here: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_13.html  Ahh think this is the one dump-config filename

Answer (score 0):

So after long hours of troubleshooting, it turns out that the main application widget was being loaded over https, while the modules were being referenced at http. I guess flash builder 4.6 enforces stricter security settings. I now reference both the widget and the modules at https, and the application is working again.

Thanks, Shaun, for the help!